# Spring Cloud Vault picking up properties from wrong profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

In my Spring Boot project I defined 4 profiles **ide,dev,test and prod**. When I ran the project using IntelliJ with profile **ide**, everything works fine and properties are retrieved from **ide** profile in the Vault. But during deployment in dev server when I select the **dev** profile using the argument `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` dev profile is being selected and but **ide** profile properties are being retrieved

**CustomVaultConfigurer.java**

```
@Configuration
public class CustomVaultConfigurer  implements VaultConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void addSecretBackends(SecretBackendConfigurer configurer)
    {
                configurer.add("secret/app/pres/ide");
        configurer.add("secret/app/pres/dev");
        configurer.add("secret/app/pres/test");
        configurer.add("secret/app/pres/prod");

        configurer.registerDefaultGenericSecretBackends(false);
        configurer.registerDefaultDiscoveredSecretBackends(true);
    }
}
```

**Error Log**:

```
2020-05-27 19:28:25.663  INFO 1 --- [           main] gov.cancer.ccr.oit.pres.PresApplication  : The following profiles are active: dev
2020-05-27 19:28:28.495  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-05-27 19:28:29.710  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1203ms. Found 55 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-27 19:28:30.142  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=87545ee5-101d-3ebb-a79a-d12f99f15e9c
2020-05-27 19:28:31.002  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@70c53dbe' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-27 19:28:31.011  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityConfig' of type [gov.cancer.ccr.oit.pres.security.MethodSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8721baa3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-27 19:28:31.033  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-27 19:28:31.608  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-05-27 19:28:31.635  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-27 19:28:31.636  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-05-27 19:28:31.778  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-27 19:28:31.778  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6069 ms
2020-05-27 19:28:32.616  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-27 19:28:32.909  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-27 19:29:03.630 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused (Connection refused). Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

but when I place **ide** profile at the end(shown below) of the list, it works

```
configurer.add("secret/app/pres/dev");
configurer.add("secret/app/pres/test");
configurer.add("secret/app/pres/prod");
configurer.add("secret/app/pres/ide");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Dumb part on my end. As per Marks [comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/issues/563#issuecomment-635157915) When you're using `configurer.add(…)` in combination with `configurer.registerDefaultGenericSecretBackends(false)` then Spring Cloud Vault does not look at `spring.profiles.active` at all but rather uses what your **VaultConfigurer** specifies.

The updated **VaultConfigurer** looks like below, and active profile is retrieved from

VaultConfigurer.java

```
@Configuration
public class CustomVaultConfigurer  implements VaultConfigurer
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void addSecretBackends(SecretBackendConfigurer configurer)
    {
        //Get active profile from environment, if none exist select DEV profile
        if(environment.getActiveProfiles().length > 0)
            configurer.add("secret/app/pres/"+environment.getActiveProfiles()[0]);
        else
            configurer.add("secret/app/pres/dev");

        configurer.registerDefaultGenericSecretBackends(false);
        configurer.registerDefaultDiscoveredSecretBackends(true);
    }
}
```